# Clojure: more idiomatic pairing of elements from lists of unequal sizes?

Tags: clojure

I would like to create a list of pairs from `cols`, and `patch`. `cols` would have much more elements. Element in `patch` would be repeated in the pairing.

For example,

```
(element-wise-patch '(1 3 5 7 9) '(2 4) '())
([1 2] [3 4] [5 2] [7 4] [9 2])
```

Here is my attempt to implement the semantics. I hope to learn more idiomatic, and simpler solution.

```
(defn element-wise-patch [cols patch patched]
      (if (<= (count cols) (count patch))
        (concat patched (map vector cols patch))
        (let [[compatible remaining] (split-at (count patch) cols)]
          (element-wise-patch remaining patch (concat patched (map vector compatible patch)))))
```

I feel that there might be already existing construct to do such patching pairing. Also my description might not be proper enough to associate similar solutions.

Please give me some pointer, or just help me define my problem clearer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
(map vector [1 3 5 7 9] (cycle [2 4]))
```

Comment: Amazingly elegant! Thanks!